# Cant Able to login because it shows an error message from firebase "email id is badly formatted"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

This is my code but couldnt find any solution , the data got uploaded in firebase , and authentication deatils my email id and details is there but , while trying to login it shows the eeror and i cant find any solution , tried with trim() function , but didnt work . so please try to help

**My Code**

```
import React ,{useState,useContext}from 'react';
import FirebaseContext from '../../store/FirebaseContext.js'

import './Login.css';
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"
[![Screen Shot for the error message][1]][1]

function Login() {
  const history=useHistory()
  const [password,setPassword]=useState('')
  const [email,setEmail]=useState('')
  const {firebase}=useContext(FirebaseContext) 
  const handleLogin=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(),password)
    .then(()=>{
      alert('LoggedIn')
      history.push("/")
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      alert(error.message)
    })

  }
  return (
    <div className='backdrop'>
      <div className="loginParentDiv">
        <img className='login-logo' src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/77/48/55/360_F_377485593_QHN6cjoNsNdOBoJNOwVRlFcHyZ0M9n3P.jpg"></img>
        <br />
        <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <label htmlFor="fname">Email</label>
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            type="email"
            
            name="email"
            placeholder='john123@gmail.com'
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="lname">Password</label>
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            type="password"
            id="lname"
            name="password"
            placeholder=''
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button>Login</button>
        </form>
        <a href='/signup'>Signup</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**My Code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an `onChange` method in your inputs. Check you are receiving your email in your state with a console.log first.

try this

```
          <input
            className="input"
            type="email"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            name="email"
            placeholder='john123@gmail.com'
          />
```

Comment: in console.log email is not coming , and i have added onchange method for the input fields , but still in console.log email is not coming , but now the popup is not coming which says email id is badly formatted , instead im getting a diffrent error.

Comment: Well, it is going to say badly formatted beacause you are not receiving any email.